# Picked StorageFile is readonly Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I use `FileOpenPicker` to get `StorageFile` in my Windows Phone 8.1 (winrt application) photo-editing application. It works fine - however I do not have access to save changes (can't open `StorageFile` with `ReadWrite` access) - `File is readonly` exception is thrown. I tried to remove read only flag from file - but it doesn't work (same exception). Is there any capability / declaration which would allow me to edit files that I have missed?

Comment: Bit confused with your question. 1. Save Changes in the sense Are you want to Replacing existing file or save as new file. & to save file you have to use filesavepicker [ http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.filesavepicker.filetypechoices.aspx ]   2. Did you tried to set capabability to access file in Manifest of your Project [ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj247542(v=vs.105).aspx ]. 

Still you face issue Please post your code that defines how you getting file & saving File..

Comment: @Kumar The problem is when I try to replace file. (or open file with .OpenAsync(FileAccess.ReadWrite)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour is by design. If the file is marked as read only by the system or another app, they did it for a reason.

Open the file with [FileAccessMode.Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.fileaccessmode.aspx) and then you can read the contents of the file. Or copy the file to your apps app data container and then modify the copy.